# Flutter : Cancel Timer In Dispose Not Working

Tags: flutter, dart

I have create running clock using timer with this code :

#### Source Code

```
class LiveClock extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LiveClockState createState() => _LiveClockState();
}

class _LiveClockState extends State<LiveClock> {
  String _timeString;
  String _dateString;

  Timer _timerClock;

  String _formatTime(DateTime dateTime) => DateFormat.Hms().format(dateTime);
  String _formatDate(DateTime dateTime) =>
      DateFormat.yMMMMEEEEd(appConfig.indonesiaLocale).format(dateTime);

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _timeString = _formatTime(DateTime.now());
    _dateString = _formatDate(DateTime.now());
    _timerClock = Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 1), _getTime);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _timerClock.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }

  void _getTime(Timer timer) {
    final DateTime now = DateTime.now();
    final String formattedTime = _formatTime(now);
    setState(() => _timeString = formattedTime);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print('This Rebuild');

    return Text(
      '$_dateString $_timeString ',
      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
    );
  }
}
```

#### Result

[image]

> But the problem is , if i navigate to another screen , the timer still running although i have dispose the timer.

[image]

did I make mistake or it's behaviour the timer ?

Comment: Hi, I have the same problem with you... I use bottom tab navigator and timer... have you found the solution of your question?

Comment: @uyhaW i change from timer to streambuilder to implement live clock. https://gist.github.com/zgramming/963c2c79fda867dcb0388a86e8787f6d

Comment: @ZeffryReynaldo Thanks for your help.. I will try to do the same

Answer (score 5):

In flutter, dispose is called on a widget when it is completely removed from the parent tree.

When using routes(navigation) in flutter.

- Using push navigation, a new screen is added on top of current screen. hence the tree (of old screen) is not completely destroyed hence dispose is not called.
- using pop. the screen is removed so is the tree. hence dispose is called.
- using push replacement. new screen replaces old screen deleting the widget tree. so dispose is called.

hope this helps

Comment: make sense. In my case i navigate between Widget with BottomNavigationBar. So with it , the timer Will not cancel? Because i worry about memory leak if i leave timer still running